# Make my Ubuntu, use more swap than RAM

Tags: command-line, gui, ram, swap, storage

So, I have 786 MB RAM with 1.6 GB Swap. I want to increase the usage of swap. In other words, i want my Ubuntu to use more Swap than My RAM. Please Tell me, how to do it

Comment: Your Swap is already bigger than the amount of RAM: 2 times the amount of RAM. So, you don't need more because probably will never be used.

Comment: post ur comment as an answer so that people will get to know about this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to increase the usage of swap, you can adjust  Ubuntu's swappiness which has a default value of 60 by editing

```
sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and changing or adding the value of

```
vm.swappiness = 80
```

or any number between 0 (swap disabled) to 100 (swap used all the time).

However the default setting of 60 should be fine for your use case.

see also [swappiness](https://sites.google.com/site/tipsandtricksforubuntu/system-tips/swappiness)

Comment: but people say that it slows down my PC!

Comment: Yes, as I said the default should be fine for you and using more swap memory will probably not lead to better performance (adding more RAM memory will). This would how ever be the answer to your question of how to make Ubuntu use swap more.

Comment: Test it for a few days. Also be sure to check the results with a watch-clock. I've ran `vm.swappiness = 100` for years without problems.